# How to place default text in row using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to place default text to all rows for particular column in jquery grid.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a class name to the cells that require a default text -in this example the class name is 'placeholder'- and target that with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('td.placeholder').text('this message to be shown');
  }
)
```

It's untested, but I think it'll do what you want, unless you need to use specific html for some reason? In which case:

```
    $('td.placeholder').html('<span class="default_text">this message to be shown</span>');
```

should work instead.

---

**Edited** in response to question (in comments):

> if I need to perform only for one last cell? thanks – kumar

If you only need to perform this action on one particular cell you can either assign an `id` or a `class` to that cell, an `id` is/must be/should be unique in the document so *only one element can have any* `id`. A class is probably still the easiest solution, since it allows for later re-use of the same code/jQuery function. Still, to advise:

```
// to select <td> element of a particular id:
$('td#element_id').text('this message to be shown');

// to select the last cell:
$('td:last').text('this message to be shown');

// to select only the last cell that has a particular class-name 'placeholder':
$('td.placeholder:last').text('this message to be shown');
```

Incidentally, you might like to read the jQuery docs, over at: [docs.jquery.com/](http://docs.jquery.com/)

Comment: Do I have to .each() or will this do the job iterating through all of them?

Comment: @Mahesh - This will perform the action on **all** cells with that class.

Comment: @Kumar, see the updated answer (below the horizontal rule), for an answer to your question in the comments.

Comment: Thank rice..But I am not able to see the default text in jquery grid row.. 

that i have 5 rows in jquery grid but at the last column for each row I am not seeing this text..

$('#table td.Myclassname:last').text('this message to be shown');

is this right what I am doig there?

Comment: @Kumar: show me the generated html for the page (view source -> copy the html for the table -> edit this question and add the code) and I'll see if anything stands out. Although looking at your comment you're selecting the last `td` element with class `Myclassname` that's a child of an element with the `id` of 'table'. Two things: do you *have* an element with an `id` of table, and is your classname spelled correctly?